# including missing values after random sampling in R (merge vectors and include missing values as 0)

Tags: r

I am trying to do many random sampling trials, and in these samplings I may not get everything every time.

Right now, what I do is

```
test <- sample(rownames(data), size=10000, replace=T, prob=data$refFraction)
```

Not every `rowname(data)` is represented in this, but I need it to be for the next step.

I would like to have it so each time I `sample` I have the same length (and order) vector so that I can combine each sampling into a matrix (which I also am unsure of how best to do - how can I make thousands of test vectors and merge them at once with one of the apply functions?)

edit: Based on answers, I came up with this:

```
trials <- function(fractions, kmers, times, ref_size) {
    replicate(times, sample(kmers, size=ref_size, replace=T, prob=fractions), simplify=F)
}

result <- trials(data$refFraction, rownames(data), 100, 1000)
mat <- matrix(result, nrow=100)
```

But I still just want the count of the number of times each thing is seen in the row, while also having zero counts so I end up with a even matrix of counts.

The desired result is something like:

```
         "A" "B" "C"
Trial1    2    5   6
Trial2    3    7   12
Trial3    0    5   14
```

dput(head(data)):

```
structure(list(refCount = c(3142L, 4102L, 1975L, 2009L, 2363L, 
2437L), refFraction = c(0.00300290255094, 0.00392040301208, 0.00188756605287, 
0.00192006086086, 0.00225838915591, 0.00232911314979), readCount = c(147L, 
719L, 356L, 418L, 745L, 766L), readFraction = c(0.00029577107721, 
0.00144666261574, 0.000716289139367, 0.000841036124312, 0.00149897586749, 
0.00154122887852), foldChange = c(2.31774884958, 0.996935198459, 
0.968959564031, 0.825477549838, 0.409869676355, 0.412907501432
), p_value = c(5.05923221341436e-321, 4.46023836252119e-170, 
2.29230878162415e-77, 1.73499617494115e-59, 2.80547347576314e-15, 
4.32620038741552e-16)), .Names = c("refCount", "refFraction", 
"readCount", "readFraction", "foldChange", "p_value"), row.names = c("AAAAA", 
"AAAAT", "AAAAG", "AAAAC", "AAATA", "AAATT"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Am a little confused. Do you need to use replacement? Are you wanting to create multiple test samples but only if they contain an example of every member of rownames(data)?

Comment: Not clear on what you're doing, but you can use `replicate` to do repeated sampling.  The result is a matrix. e.g. `replicate(2, sample(5))`

Comment: Thanks.  So based on your example result, how many trials are there? By the way, I'm not notified of your edits so you may just want to comment here for a faster response.

Comment: In the example result, 3 trials would have been done. In the first trial the rowname "A" got sampled twice, "B" 5 times, etc. The tricky thing is that In the third trial, "A" did not get sampled at all, but I want to still maintain knowledge of that.

Comment: As you probably know, there was an issue with the comment notifications yesterday.  Did you get this all sorted out?

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what you are trying to do, but it seems like this might help.

`replicate` is great for repeated sampling.  Here I create a 5 row data frame `d`, and then sample the row names ten separate times.  When used this way, `replicate` results in a matrix, so it sounds like you may want this method.

```
> d <- data.frame(x = 1:5, y = 6:10)
> replicate(10, sample(rownames(d)))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,] "5"  "1"  "1"  "3"  "4"  "1"  "4"  "5"  "3"  "1"  
# [2,] "4"  "5"  "2"  "2"  "3"  "5"  "1"  "2"  "1"  "2"  
# [3,] "1"  "4"  "5"  "5"  "5"  "4"  "3"  "3"  "2"  "3"  
# [4,] "2"  "3"  "3"  "1"  "1"  "2"  "2"  "4"  "4"  "5"  
# [5,] "3"  "2"  "4"  "4"  "2"  "3"  "5"  "1"  "5"  "4"
```

Comment: Being a character matrix or a number matrix is the same thing really, because I want to count the number of times I randomly sample each row name. Based on your comment I wrote a function I will edit into the OP, but I am still not sure how to go from this to counts and still have a evenly sized matrix.

Comment: Okay, yes.  It would be best if you provide a bit more information, and the desired result would definitely help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up doing it:

```
trial_fn <- function(counts) {
   replicate(num_trials, sample(counts, size=trial_size, replace=F), simplify=F)
}

tableize <- function(x) {
    tmp <- matrix(table(factor(x, levels=1:1024)))[,1]
    tmp/sum(tmp)
}

counts <- vector()
for (i in 1:1024) {
    counts <- c(counts, rep(i, times=data[i,]$readCount))
}

trials <- trial_fn(counts)
trial_table <- sapply(trials, tableize)
```

Using `factor` with `levels` and then using `table` on the result is the answer to the original question.